# In EventBridge rule, how do you match only those events emitted by a specific instance of Amazon Connect?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-event-bridge, amazon-connect

[Here is the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/contact-events.html) from Amazon for how to set up an EventBridge rule that sources Contact Events from Amazon Connect and publishes said events to a target destination.

QUESTION:  said documentation does not explain how to match events emitted from a specific instance of Amazon Connect.  How can that be done?

I am guessing the Event Pattern for the EventBridge rule can be used to select only those events emitted from a specific instance of Amazon Connect.  But it would be useful to know whether that is the recommended approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am guessing the Event Pattern for the EventBridge rule can be used to select only those events emitted from a specific instance of Amazon Connect.

The documentation you linked in your question specifically states that there is an `InstanceArn` attribute in the event that is the: "Amazon Resource Name (ARN) for the Amazon Connect instance in which the agent's user account is created."

So you would create a filter in EventBridge for your specific Amazon Connect instance's ARN.

> But it would be useful to know whether that is the recommended approach.

Yes of course. That is a standard pattern for filtering events in EventBridge.

Comment: can you take a look at a related permissions question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77027704/can-amazon-connect-instance-without-putevent-permissions-still-publish-contact